# Date and time a file was copied to a directory

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

Is there a way to see what time a file get copied to a directory? Looks like Date modified column in windows explorer shows the date and time when the file got created.

Answer (score 1):

You could try checking this via the command line. 
[Here](http://www.windows-commandline.com/get-file-modified-date-time/) are some commands that may help.

#### Using 'dir'

This, for example, gives the last modified time of this file:

```
dir /T:W  d:\test.pdf
```

And this gives the date/time for all files and sub-directories in the current one:

```
dir /T:W
```

#### Using 'forfiles'

Modified datetime for all files in current dir:

```
forfiles /C "cmd /c echo @file @fdate @ftime"
```

Or just the pdf files within the directory:

```
forfiles /M *.pdf /C "cmd /c echo @file @fdate @ftime"
```

#### Using 'cp' in linux

I don't know who useful this would be for you, but on Linux machines you can use this option when coping files:

```
$ cp --no-preserve=timestamps my-file.pdf my-copy.pdf
```

This way the copy will have its own creation time and won't depend on the original file.